# How to inject a bean in my own WireMock Extension in Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I successfully registered my own Wiremock extension by using the spring.factories approach described in the documentation (8.5.6 Registering Your Own WireMock Extension) but I also need to inject a bean in the class that implements the WireMockExtensions in order to pass it down to my custom extension, to provide some services to my custom extension.

I tried to use Autowired in the class that implements the WireMockExtensions but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `WireMockExtension` declared as a bean ?

Comment: it's declared on the spring.factories file...

Comment: my problem is this spring.factories approach... I can instantiate my service with the new keyword in the WireMockExtensions implementation but then my service also depends on other beans and this wouldn't scale so well as I need to say 'new' everywhere, I would like to take advantage of the Spring DI if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't out of the box. Since we're using the `spring.factories` mechanism, it's creating the extensions via `new`.

What you can do is try to access the application context statically from your extension. What you can do is to create a bean in test scope that will contain a static field in which  `applicationContext` will be injected. Then from outside Spring context you will be able to access it.

Also, why do you need Spring context in a WireMock extension?

Comment: I see. I was indeed already using a static approach, but I needed more than one service so I thought to ask it here to see if I could use Spring goodness because this static approach is a bit messy...
I don't follow completely you suggestion, my approach is by declaring a static field in the class that is a bean, and then use PostConstruct to assign the static field to the 'this' reference, then I can get the bean statically...
I need Spring context because I'm refactoring an app that act as a stub server in to a SCC boot stubrunner, and my original app depends on services

Comment: Yeah, we're talking about basically the same thing